# Nifi docker installation

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm just new to `Nifi`. I was able to install `Nifi` and see it in `webbrowser`. Now as next step i want to connect to `sql server`, nevertheless it seems i have to install jdbc as well and here is my issue when i look at tutorials all referencing to something called "docker" and advising to install `jdbc` from there. When i go into `cmd` and type `docker` `cmd` not recognize it. Can anyone tell me how to install it and what it is?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need of docker for this use case.

All you have to do is download and install SQL server from official downloads page, if you don't have server setup.

Installation guide - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

You also need to download jar file which has JDBC driver stuff - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

In NiFi, you can use PutDatabaseRecord processor to insert/update/delete rows from table. This processor internally uses DBCPConnectionPool controller services to get database connections.

DBCPConnectionPool controller service requires below properties to be set.

- Database connection url -  **jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=dbname**
- Driver class name -
  **com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver**
- Driver (jar) location -
  /tmp/**sqlserver.jar** (Example only)

[PutDatabaseRecord Processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ezz0.png)

[DBCPConnectionPool controller service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQp12.png)

Comment: What for is docker?

Comment: Much thanks for these details @arunkvelu!

@Arie for docker you can download the drivers and .jar when building the docker image or I'm sure there exist a random image with the drivers already within.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may want to google how to install Docker and what it is, it's already explained in many places.